# Find the area of the region that lies inside the first curve and outside the second curve.

Tags: polar-coordinates

How do I define the range of the area of the integration in this question?
The first curve is 
$$r = 5-5\sin{\theta}$$ and the second curve is $$r=5$$

Comment: i have done  5-5 sin x =5,  x = 0,pi,pi.  I thought the range is 0 to pi but the answer is pi to two pi.  I know the formula of the question, but I have no clue about the range.

Comment: Does $x$ here mean the polar angle commonly denoted by $\theta$?

Comment: It is very important to actually make graphs. Because only then you can observe the orientation of the curves. Because if you want to describe the region that is outside the first and inside the second curve, that happens when you travel from $\pi$ to $2\pi$. Without any graphs, this is very difficult to understand. On your interval $0$ to $\pi$, the particles traveling the curves are in the first and second quadrant, which is not where you want to be

Comment: The first curve, $r=5-5\sin(\theta)$ is shown by Shraddheya Shendre, and the second curve, $r=5$ is simply a circle around the origin of radius $5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: plot of $r = 5 - 5\sin(\theta)$]

This [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=8d8e2c27bcaa121d6ee0de4b98774bb4) of $r = 5 - 5\sin(\theta)$ should clear your doubt.